# How can I run all the bash process as background?

Tags: bash, shell

I don't think that running a process on foreground is any way useful.  So I'd like to run all process on background.  Is that possible?
Also tell me if there is any problem associated with doing so.

Comment: What do you mean by "all" process? Are you starting the process that you want to be in background? Please explain your requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can adapt the code from this question: https://superuser.com/questions/175799/does-bash-have-a-hook-that-is-run-before-executing-a-command

Basically this uses the `DEBUG` trap to run a command before whatever you've typed on the command line. So, this:

```
preexec () { :; }
preexec_invoke_exec () {
    [ -n "$COMP_LINE" ] && return  # do nothing if completing
    [ "$BASH_COMMAND" = "$PROMPT_COMMAND" ] && return # don't cause a preexec for $PROMPT_COMMAND
    local this_command=$(HISTTIMEFORMAT= history 1);
    preexec "$this_command" &
}
trap 'preexec_invoke_exec' DEBUG
```

Runs the command, but with `&` afterwards, backgrounding the process.

Note that this will have other rather weird effects on your terminal, and anything supposed to run in the foreground (command line browsers, mail readers, interactive commands, anything requiring input, etc.) will have issues.

You can try this out by just typing `bash`, which will execute another shell. Paste the above code, and if things start getting weird, just `exit` out of the shell and things will reset.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean bash script? Jush add `&` at the end. Example :

`$ ./myscript &`

Answer (score 0):

While it might be possible to do something clever like suggested by @pgl, it's not a good idea. Processes running in the background don't show you their output in a useful way. So, if all processes are automatically sent to the background, your terminal will be flooded with their various standard output and standard error messages but you will have no way of knowing what came from what, your terminal will be next to useless and confusion will ensue.

So, yes there is a very good reason to keep processes in the foreground: to see what they're doing and be able to control them easily. To give an even more concrete example, any program that requires you to interact with it can't be run in the background. This includes things that ask for `Continue [Y/N]?` or things like `sudo` that ask for your password. If you just blindly make everything run int the background such commands will just silently hang.